# Rotating a circle with mouse with direction

Tags: c#, rotation, atan2

I am rotating a circle with a mouse but I want there to be a limit on how far the circle can be rotated. (Lets say 3 full times). When it reaches it's limit it can no longer be turned in that same direction, but the opposite direction it can be. I got it stopping after the max turns but now I'm trying to find the direction and every time my mouse passes the x-axis of the circle the direction changes because atan2 gives me the angle relative to the x-axis. So the new mouse position is in one quadrant and the last position is in another quadrant so subtracting these angles doesn't give me what I want. Did I explain this well? Any suggestions?

```
private void HelmPb_MouseMove(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
    {
        if ((e.Button != MouseButtons.Left) || _dontTurn) return;
        double angle = OffsetAngle();
        Point temp = MousePosition;
        float degrees = Convert.ToSingle(angle - _offsetAngle);
        float diff = _lastHelmAngle - degrees;
        float absDiff = Math.Abs(diff) % 360;
        if (absDiff > 180) absDiff = 360 - absDiff;
        double angle1 = Math.Atan2(_lastHelmPoint.Y, _lastHelmPoint.X);
        if (angle1 < 0) angle1 += 2*Math.PI;
        double angle2 = Math.Atan2(temp.Y, temp.X);
        if (angle2 < 0) angle2 += 2*Math.PI;
        double direction = angle1 - angle2;
        direction = direction*(180/Math.PI);
        _deltaHelmTurn += Convert.ToSingle(absDiff);
        if (_deltaHelmTurn >= (_maxHelmTurn*360.0))
        {
            if (direction > 0 && _lastHelmDirection > 0)
            {
                _deltaHelmTurn = Convert.ToSingle(_maxHelmTurn*360.0);
                degrees = Convert.ToSingle(_maxHelmTurn*360.0)%360;
            }
        }
        _lastHelmDirection = direction;
        _lastHelmPoint = MousePosition;
        _lastHelmAngle = Convert.ToSingle(degrees);
        _sameHelmRotation = Convert.ToSingle(degrees);
        HelmPb.Image.Dispose();
        WaterDepthPlot.Update();
        HelmPb.Image = RotateImage(_originalHelmImage, -degrees);
        HelmPb.Update();
    }

private double OffsetAngle()
    {
        int helmXMid = HelmPb.PointToScreen(Point.Empty).X + (HelmPb.Width / 2);
        int helmYMid = HelmPb.PointToScreen(Point.Empty).Y + (HelmPb.Height / 2);
        double angle = AngleFromPoints(MousePosition, new Point(helmXMid, helmYMid));
        return angle;
    }

private double AngleFromPoints(Point pt1, Point pt2)
    {
        Point p = new Point(pt1.X - pt2.X, pt1.Y - pt2.Y);
        double alpha;
        if (p.Y == 0) alpha = p.X > 0 ? 0d : 180d;
        else
        {
            double f = 1d * p.X / (Math.Sqrt(p.X * p.X + p.Y * p.Y));
            alpha = Math.Acos(f) * 180d / Math.PI;
            if (p.Y > 0) alpha = 360d - alpha;
        }
        return alpha;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

The direction of rotation between two vectors is equivalent to the sign of their cross product.

```
//Returns 1 for CCW, -1 for CW, 0 for no change
private int Direction(Point from, Point to)
{
    double cross = (from.x * to.y) - (from.y * to.x);
    return Math.Sign(cross);
}
```

Comment: There seems to be a problem. Example, If the start point was (129,17) and end point was (136,19) this is CW, cross = (129*19) - (17*136) = 139.0 which means its CCW. Am I doing something wrong?

Comment: @user3529319 - Going from (129,17) to (136,19) is CCW. [View Graph](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=vectors+%28129%2C17%29+%28136%2C19%29)